# Get value of submit button from Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, form-submit

The value of the submit buttons are always null in the Action.

What do I need to change to know which submit button has been clicked?

```
<form id="actionInvitation">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                @Model.TeamInviteBy
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>       
                    <input type="submit" name="actionBtn" id="acceptBtn" value="Accept Invitation" />
                    <input type="submit" name="actionBtn" id="declineBtn" value="Decline Invitation" />
                </form>


$('#actionInvitation').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#actionInvitation')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ActionInvitation", "Home")',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#invitationActionMessage").append('Invitation Accepted');
            }
        });
    });

//Action
public async Task<IActionResult> ActionInvitation(UserViewModel userViewModel, string acceptBtn, string declineBtn)
```

Comment: Hi @Ryn901,If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer, it will be helpful to people who have the same problem later.

Answer (score 0):

Your `formData` will not contain the objects you need to pass.

You can change your code like below:

```
<form id="actionInvitation">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            @Model.TeamInviteBy
            <input type="hidden" name="TeamInviteBy" value="@Model.TeamInviteBy">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="actionBtn" onclick="Send(event,this)"  value="Accept Invitation" />
<input type="submit" name="actionBtn" onclick="Send(event,this)"  value="Decline Invitation" />
</form>
@section scripts{ 
<script>
    function Send(ev,el) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = $("input[name='TeamInviteBy']").val();
        var value = $(el).val();
         $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ActionInvitation", "Home")',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            data: { TeamInviteBy: data, actionBtn: value},
                success: function (data) {
                $("#invitationActionMessage").append('Invitation Accepted');
                }
                });
    }
</script>
}
```

Action:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ActionInvitation( UserViewModel userViewModel , string actionBtn)
    {
      if(actionBtn="Accept Invitation")
       {
        //...
       }
       else
       {
       }
    }
```

Result:
[image]